# MySQL - Remove redundant field after a query

Tags: mysql

I'm performing a query on a multiple JOIN table:

```
SELECT  TableA.*,
        TableB.Data             as Data_B,
        TableC.Data             as Data_C,
        TableD.Data             as Data_D,
        TableE.*
FROM TableA     JOIN TableB         ON TableB.ID = TableA.ID
                JOIN TableC         ON TableC.ID = TableB.ID
                JOIN TableD         ON TableD.ID = TableC.ID
                JOIN TableE         ON TableE.ID = TableA.ID
WHERE DataToFind = '$SubmittedData'
```

It works good, but since TableA is the main table and TableE is a multiple child table associated to TableA by key ID, when I perform a search on a TableA field I get redoundant rows of TableA as many as TableE records.

Since I want to DISTINCT only AFTER I've performed my search, my ideal query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM
(
SELECT  TableA.*,
        TableB.Data             as Data_B,
        TableC.Data             as Data_C,
        TableD.Data             as Data_D,
        TableE.*
FROM TableA     JOIN TableB         ON TableB.ID = TableA.ID
                JOIN TableC         ON TableC.ID = TableB.ID
                JOIN TableD         ON TableD.ID = TableC.ID
                JOIN TableE         ON TableE.ID = TableA.ID
WHERE DataToFind = '$SubmittedData'
)
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
```

But it's not working since I'm getting "Unexpected token" and other syntax error.

Can you help me to find how it should be correctly formatted?

p.s. I don't care if I lose some TableE records since I can recover them when needed using found IDs.

Comment: relation to php is what? there's only mysql here and a variable that we don't know how/where it's assigned as.

Comment: The problem is not associated to PHP, it's just a random variable as example. Focus should be only on MySQL.

Comment: please don't mistag; I removed it in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want distinct ids, then put that all in a single select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableA.ID
FROM TableA JOIN
     TableB
     ON TableB.ID = TableA.ID JOIN
     TableC
     ON TableC.ID = TableB.ID JOIN
     TableD
     ON TableD.ID = TableC.ID JOIN
     TableE
     ON TableE.ID = TableA.ID
WHERE DataToFind = '$SubmittedData';
```

Your version has a problem, because there are two columns called `ID` in the subquery.  That will generate another error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine. It's just missing the table alias for the subquery like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM
(
    SELECT  tableA.*,
            TableB.Data             as Data_B,
            TableC.Data             as Data_C,
            TableD.Data             as Data_D
            TableE.*
    FROM tableA     JOIN tableB         ON tableB.ID = tableA.ID
                    JOIN tableC         ON tableC.ID = tableB.ID
                    JOIN tableD         ON tableD.ID = tableC.ID
                    JOIN tableE         ON tableE.ID = tableA.ID
    WHERE DataToFound = '$SubmittedData'
) xxx            <-- missing
WHERE ProcedureID IS NOT NULL
```